# Accessing Subdirectory in public_html using CakePhp 2.0

Tags: cakephp-2.0, subdirectory, public-html

my question is very simple.

I have a /cms subdirectory on my /public_html directory.

when I try to do: mysite.com/cms cake tries to find cms controller instead of showing the index.php that /cms contains.

How can I make cake to search this folder in the public_html?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a folder that belongs to your app or is it an external one? This problem is most likely because your public_html folder is your cake root folder (or at least you have the .htaccess for routing there)

You may want to have your cake app on a subfolder instead of having it on the root of youe webserver

If the content belongs to yout app, you can put The cms folder on the `wwwroot` folder of your application or follow [this](http://richardathome.wordpress.com/2007/08/13/cakephp-tip-routing-for-static-pages/) tip and move all from cms to `Pages` folder

Comment: the thing is I already put a /blog folder in my public_html. This /blog contains a wordpress instance and it works perfect when I type mysite.com.blog . Shouldn't it work with this new subfolder?

Comment: oh, and is a external folder...!